# Recorte de imagem por seleção de mouse c#

Tags: c#, imagem

Gostaria de saber de que maneira consigo em c# no windows forms capturar o x e y do mouse para estar fazendo o recorte da imagem por meio da área selecionada pelo usuário.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-crop-and-scale-images?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 de uma olhada nesse tutorial

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q63GV5tnXN0